# How do I replace variables in python class?

Tags: python, class, replace, instance

I was instructed to define a class which takes 3 variables: (which looks something like this)

```
class random(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        self.result= #calculations with a,b and c.
    def __str__(self):
        #functions so that self.result prints correctly
```

However, I also have to write another function in the above class:

```
    def read(#takes whatever parameter I need)
         #functions which I dont know how to write
```

This function should allow me to read from another file (lets call it file.txt"), and replace the self.a, self.b and self.c with information from that file, if you know what I mean? like for example:

```
itemA=random(1,2,3)
```

and file.txt contains three lines:

```
6
7
8
```

running the following:

```
itemA.read()
```

is suppose to replace the 1,2,3 in the parameter as 6,7,8, so that

```
itemA=random(6,7,8)
```

How can I achieve that? I already wrote the part that reads and reproduce random(6,7,8),with:

```
fileHandle=open('file.txt', 'r')
fileHandle.readlines()
#some codes that turn string into integer/floats
fileHandle.close()
random(#put integers in)
```

however I am not able to update itemA from random(1,2,3) to random(6,7,8) without writing manually:

```
itemA=itemA.read() #in python shell
```

btw itemA is just an example name, it can be named anything so I cant actually use itemA in my calculations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a method on your class, you can manipulate attributes by setting them on `self`, just like you did in the `__init__` method.

All you need to do then is set those attributes after reading. You probably want your `read()` method to take a filename too:

```
def read(self, filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        self.a = int(fh.readline())
        self.b = int(fh.readline())
        self.c = int(fh.readline())
        self.result = # same calculation
```

So when you call `itemA.read()` it'll alter the attributes *in place*; there is no need to return anything here.

You could *reuse* the `__init__` method to set those attributes, and avoid having to duplicatoe the calculation for the `self.result` attribute:

```
class random(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.result = #calculations with a,b and c.

    def read(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as fh:
            a = int(fh.readline())
            b = int(fh.readline())
            c = int(fh.readline())
            self.__init__(a, b, c)  # set the attributes plus result
```

or you could share a *separate* method between `__init__` and `read()`:

```
class random(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self._calculate_result()

    def _calculate_result(self)
        self.result = #calculations with self.a, self.b and self.c.

    def read(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as fh:
            self.a = int(fh.readline())
            self.b = int(fh.readline())
            self.c = int(fh.readline())
            self._calculate_result()  # set the result
```

It would work something like this:

```
itemA = random(1, 2, 3)
itemA.read('file.txt')
# now itemA.a is set to 4, itemA.b is set to 5 and item.c is set to 6
```

It *could* be that you wanted to produce an instance of the class `random` either by providing `a`, `b` and `c` *directly*, *or* by reading from a file. This is a little more advanced, but that means you are providing two different *factory methods*, two different ways to produce instances of `random`. I tend to use class methods to implement extra factory methods:

```
class random(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.result = #calculations with a,b and c.

    @classmethod
    def from_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as fh:
            a = int(fh.readline())
            b = int(fh.readline())
            c = int(fh.readline())
            return cls(a, b, c)  # create a new instance of this class
```

I renamed the `read` method to `from_file()` to document better that this is a factory method. You'd use it like this:

```
itemA = random(1, 2, 3)
itemB = random.from_file('file.txt')
```

This creates two separate instances, one with values provided directly, the other by reading from a file.

Comment: You should mention that `random` is a bad name for an own class.

Comment: @Matthias: `random` is not a built-in. Sure, it could collide with the standard library module, but only if you were to import it as a global. It is fine here.